# MySQL CREATE statement in SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server, and has a need to convert a MySQL `CREATE` statement similar to following to SQL Server. It contains 'NOT NULL' column, and some other types. Is it possible for someone to provide this? There is very few tools to convert from MySQL -> SQL Server though there are several to do it the other way around.

```
CREATE TABLE a 
( a VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
, b VARCHAR(150)
, c INT
, d DOUBLE
, e BIGINT
, f SMALLINT
) ;
```

Comment: Have you tried to run it as is, in SQL-Server? And correct any errors you will get, one by one?

Comment: If it looks like SQL, it just might be SQL. Have you tried it? Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: The `CREATE TABLE` manuals for both DBMS are easy to find. So are the available datatypes (and the differences)

Comment: I didn't try this on SQL-server because I don't have one right now. I'm using this via Java, and I don't get to use SQL-Server.

Comment: @ypercube This query is not validated in MS SQL. I tried this with SQL Fiddle that njk has provided.

Comment: Yeah, I know it isn't. **[SQL-Server datatypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx)** are not identical with MySQL ones.

Comment: You could have simply looked at the manual to find out the correct data types and syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server supports NOT NULL (as does every SQL implementation I know of)

So something like:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    cola VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    colb VARCHAR(150),
    colc INT,
    cold FLOAT,
    cole BIGINT,
    colf SMALLINT
);
```

ought to work just fine.

Note that SQL Server does not offer a DOUBLE data type, but that can be done with other data types, such as decimal if you really need to store that much data.

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN website is a very valuable resource to get you started. You can read the documentation on `CREATE TABLE` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx).

Use [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) to test your `CREATE` statement if you do not yet have the platform.

Comment: Thank you for providing the link to SQL Fiddle. I was missing an online tool to do SQL validation.